# Standardize group names using a vector of possible matches

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I need to standardize how subgroups are referred to in a data set. To do this I need to identify when a variable matches one of several strings and then set a new variable with the standardized name. I am trying to do that with the following:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4), b = c(depression_male, depression_female, depression_hsgrad, depression_collgrad))
TestVector <- "male"
for (i in TestVector) {
  df$grpl <- grepl(paste0(i), df$b)
  df[ which(df$grpl == TRUE),]$standard <- "male"
}
```

The test vector will frequently have multiple elements. The grepl works (I was going to deal with the male/female match confusion later but I'll take suggestions on that) but the subsetting and setting a new variable doesn't. It would be better (and work) if I could transform the grepl output directly into the standard name variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only real issue is that you need to initialize the `standard` column. But we can simplify your code a bit:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4), b = c("depression_male", "depression_female", "depression_hsgrad", "depression_collgrad"))
TestVector <- "male"
df$standard <- NA
for (i in TestVector) {
  df[ grepl(i, df$b), "standard"] <- "male"
}
df
#   a                   b standard
# 1 1     depression_male     male
# 2 2   depression_female     male
# 3 3   depression_hsgrad     <NA>
# 4 4 depression_collgrad     <NA>
```

Then you've got the issue that the "male" pattern matches "female" as well.

Perhaps you're looking for `sub` instead? It works like find/replace:

```
df$standard = sub(pattern = "depression_", replacement = "", df$b)
df
#   a                   b standard
# 1 1     depression_male     male
# 2 2   depression_female   female
# 3 3   depression_hsgrad   hsgrad
# 4 4 depression_collgrad collgrad
```

It's hard to generalize what will be best in your case without more example input/output pairs. If all your data is of the form "depression_" this will work well. Or maybe the standard name is always after an underscore, so you could use `pattern = ".*_"` to replace everything before the last underscore. Or maybe something else... Hopefully these ideas give you a good start.

Comment: Your code suggestion works great! I didn't know you could do that with subsetting, which is cool. I can't use sub as the variable b is coded by something like 8 different people who all use their own patterns. I'm working on getting everyone on the same page, but one step at a time.

Comment: The other option with `sub` would be to use regex to match the entire string if it contains your pattern, e.g., `sub(pattern = ".*male.*, replacement = "male", df$b)`. But I'd probably stick with what I have in the answer, in this case at least.